# Intellij error during artifact deployment. Jboss

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jboss, server, wildfly

I'm trying to run a project on intellij. I'm using wildfly and its configuration is correct because if i click on run, the project starts normally, but if i click on debug it gives the following error.

I found some threads with this question but none resolved the problem. Could someone help please?

Note: I start wildfly with standalone-full configuration

Thanks

```
Connected to server
[2016-12-21 04:23:04,640] Artifact catix-web:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
16:23:04,740 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "Catix" (runtime-name: "Catix.war")
16:23:06,522 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry xercesImpl.jar in /home/ricardo/IdeaProjects/Catix/catix-web/target/Catix/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.6.0.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:23:06,522 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry xml-apis.jar in /home/ricardo/IdeaProjects/Catix/catix-web/target/Catix/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.6.0.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:23:06,525 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry xbean.jar in /home/ricardo/IdeaProjects/Catix/catix-web/target/Catix/WEB-INF/lib/batik-js-1.7.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:23:06,583 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."Catix.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."Catix.war".PARSE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "Catix.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:163)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.ejb.default-resource-adapter-name-service not found
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl.getRequiredService(ServiceContainerImpl.java:669)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.getDefaultResourceAdapterName(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:274)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.processMessageBeans(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:154)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.processAnnotations(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:81)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.processAnnotations(AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.deploy(AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:81)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:156)
    ... 5 more

16:23:06,585 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "Catix")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Catix.war\".PARSE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"Catix.war\".PARSE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment \"Catix.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.ejb.default-resource-adapter-name-service not found"}}
16:23:06,586 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "Catix.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Catix.war\".PARSE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"Catix.war\".PARSE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment \"Catix.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.ejb.default-resource-adapter-name-service not found"}}
16:23:06,606 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment Catix (runtime-name: Catix.war) in 20ms
16:23:06,607 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (management-handler-thread - 2) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."Catix.war".PARSE

[2016-12-21 04:23:06,633] Artifact catix-web:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2016-12-21 04:23:06,634] Artifact catix-web:war exploded: java.lang.Exception: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Catix.war\".PARSE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"Catix.war\".PARSE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment \"Catix.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.ejb.default-resource-adapter-name-service not found"}}
```

Comment: How are you starting the server? Are you using the `standalone-full.xml` configuration?

Comment: Already solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove Xalan and Xerces JARs from your WEB-INF/lib.  The server ought to be using its own versions of those.

I cut & pasted the last error message into Google and got [this](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/197274) back.

Comment: No, same as before

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's not gonna work, I thought that this command in the startup script (Run/Debug Configuration -> Startup/Connection tab) was for both the run and the debug. It turns out that you need to explicitly select the debug and put the same configuration in the startup script. Lack of attention on my part